# Add an 'all or nothing rollback' on a before filter on a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model like this

```
class Status < ApplicationRecord

  after_save :create_feed

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity

  has_one :feed, as: :linkable, class_name: 'Feed', dependent: :destroy

  private

  def create_feed
    activity.feeds.new(linkable_id: id, linkable_type: class.name, category: 'status', user_id: user_id, notes: "Status Updated to #{status.titlecase} (#{.note})").save
  end

end
```

I omitted my validations but they ensure that all the fields are required for the `create_feed` to successfully save.  Is there a way to ensure the parent model commit fails if the child feed is not successful?  This would be a rollback of the parent if that child create somehow fails.

Comment: I've not tried this, but perhaps you could throw an exception: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution

Comment: You can create a process by which the entire event chain is wrapped in a transaction. That being said your relationships seem a bit odd. Since this class says it has one feed but `create_feed` is creating a `Feed` through `activity`? I am not sure how this is even working

Comment: [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399258/rollback-entire-transaction-within-nested-transaction) can better explain an "All or nothing rollback" as requested in the title

Comment: You have me thinking now. I could go the other direction and create this through the Feed controller then create the associated Status record.  I agree it’s a bit odd and hard to explain here.

Comment: The transaction is what I thinking when I asked the 'all or nothing' title.  Now that I see that post you referenced that seems exactly what I want.

Comment: @engineersmnky feel free to post an answer summarizing your comments here - this is exactly what I am looking for.  I wrapped this back in my controller.  The only thing you should note is keep the ! on the saves otherwise the Transaction still completes.

Comment: @DanTappin yes raising an exception is the important part because that will trigger the actual ROLLBACK. Other than the use of transactions I have too many additional questions about bothe the post and your comments to feel that offering an answer would be useful. That being said 1) if you found my other post helpful feel free to upvote; 2) you can always answer your own question based on what you've learned and your design changes.

Comment: I will check that - my transaction wouldn’t rollback without that. The first save was executed and the second failed silently.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
after_create :create_feed


def create_feed
  activity.feeds.create(linkable_id: id, linkable_type: class.name, category: 'status', user_id: user_id, notes: "Status Updated to #{status.titlecase} (#{.note})")

  delete unless feed.persisted?
end
```

Comment: That works but what I was looking for was to avoid the create the months first place. My code works and if the parent is not valid it won’t save.  I can’t imagine a scenario that the child create would fail but I wanted to add a second.

Comment: It sounds like you will need a transaction. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yes - now I am tying to understand how to do this.  I originally had this logic in my controller then moved to the model with the after_save.  Now I think I need it back in the controller.  Does the transaction return true or false?

Comment: The logic belongs in the model. I think that the block would evaluate to the last instruction.