# How ActiveRecord::Rollback behaves in nested begin-rescue blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have below code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  begin
    account.save
    # outer statement
    begin
      user.save
      # inner statement
    rescue StandardError
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  rescue StandardError
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

If there is an exception in 'inner statement', only 'user' will be rollbacked, right? 'account' won't be rollbacked in that case, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code there is a single database transaction, and it is all-or-nothing. Rolling back a transaction will roll back all the changes made in that transaction, regardless of where you issue the rollback.

You can nest transactions as well, but be wary that by default transactions are squished together, so even if you add a second transaction inside first transaction:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  begin
    account.save
    # outer statement
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      begin
        user.save
        # inner statement
      rescue StandardError
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  rescue StandardError
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

This will still result in the single transaction, and rollback will cancel all the changes.

To ask for a real subtransaction, you need to add `request_new: true` to the inner transaction:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  begin
    account.save
    # outer statement
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(require_new: true) do
      begin
        user.save
        # inner statement
      rescue StandardError
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  rescue StandardError
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

**However**, at the moment the only database supporting true nested transaction is MS-SQL. Rails at the moment handles this using save points - so don't be confused by the logs.

Comment: I don't believe your second example is accurate based on the [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#label-Nested+transactions) because `user.save` occurs in the parent transaction and the "child" transaction just swallows the Rollback.  For anyone that stumbles across this and is interested in the inverse reaction where a ROLLBACK in any "nested" transaction will ROLLBACK the entire transaction chain. You can find that information [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399258/rollback-entire-transaction-within-nested-transaction)